# Download and display html files

Tags: android, html, webview

I have to download contents of an HTML file (which uses image) via REST API. Then store them for offline use. When needed I want to display the HTML page with a `WebView` (of course with image). The REST result should look something like:

```
{
"id": 45,
"html": "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My Heading</h1><p>My paragraph.</p><img src='abc.com/images/54289847.jpg' alt='any' width='104' height='142'></body></html>",
"imagePath": "abc.com/images/54289847.jpg",
"moreData": "something more"
}
```

So, what will be the most efficient way to do this?

I'm planning encrypted contents of HTML will go to local storage in any file. Same thing for the images. And then decrypt, and load to `WebView`. But will it work for images?

I don't need any code, just suggest me a way.

Answer (score 2):

in this example string is loaded to webview

String summary = "You scored **192** points.";
       webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);

what if you get string from input stream  and pass it to web view      IOUtils.toString(context.getResources().openRawResource())

Answer (score 2):

Im not an android developer, but can't you get the "image data-url" and use as the image itself?
For example your avatar's data-url is:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

If you paste this in your computer's browser(as url) and/or in `<img>` tag, you'll see your avatar.

Comment: Thought about this. Going to have a try

Comment: It is a solution but not efficient as the whole file will be loaded in the memory. So, waiting for a better idea.

Comment: Is there any possible way to display anything on display without passing it through RAM??? I don't think so! Everything will pass memory before going somewhere!